# javascript / jquery setting var not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rather perplexing problem that I cannot seem to resolve.

The line in question is

```
var currentactive = $("products-grid-pager ul li[class='active'] a").attr("pageid");
```

This var is always returning as undefined, however if I pause the debugger after this line and use the console to get `$("products-grid-pager ul li[class='active'] a").attr("pageid");` then I get the desired result.

Why will my var not set?

Comment: Is the element you're selecting available when the page loads, or is it added dynamically afterward?

Comment: based on the query itself, you are selecting an element `<products-grid-pager />`. I think you want to query a class (but i can't see that, since you have no code example). * add a jsfiddle

Comment: Instead of li[class='active'] use li.active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does products-grid-pager match a class or an ID?
because

```
<products-grid-pager></products-grid-pager>
```

doesn't exist! ;-)

try

```
 $(".products-grid-pager") 
 $("#products-grid-pager")
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly it, the fact the console found it anyway completely threw me.